# Split a string with condition

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string variable that contains csv value like this:

```
string str = "105, c#, vb, 345, 53, sql51";
```

so now i want to get only alphanumeric items in a **list** or **array** without **using loop**.

required result:

```
string result = "c#, vb, sql51";
```

Or in list Or in array...

Comment: I have tried to split using this:

string[] strArray = str.split(',');

and then loop one by one and check is numeric..

Comment: What do you mean by 'without using loop'?

Comment: `105` *is* alphanumeric... Did you mean "get only substrings which are not numbers"?

Comment: You're considering wrongly "alphanumeric" meaning. It doesn't mean "strict combination of letters and numbers", but "allows combination of letters and numbers, but not special characters". So "c#" it's not allowed while the others are accepted.

Comment: `C#` is not alphanumeric.

Answer (score 5):

```
string str = "105, c#, vb, 345, 53, sql51";
var separator = ", ";
int dummy;

var parts = str.Split(new[]{separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Where(s => !int.TryParse(s, out dummy));

string result = string.Join(separator, parts);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

prints:

```
c#, vb, sql51
```

Comment: Your solution is wrong. "C#" is not alphanumeric since "#" character is not allowed while "105" does.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if the question is unclear, how can we provide an answer :) And, What about "105.0"? It's a string or a number (not an Integer, but a number anyway)? It fits with OP conception of "alphanumeric".

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi `"C#" is not alphanumeric` - this is a question to the OP, because it **does** appear in the result set.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I agree, but what about "105.0" in your algorithm? It will be part of "parts"? Is it numeric or not?

Answer (score 4):

Split using the `Split` method, filter with a LINQ expression, and call `ToArray` or `ToList` on the result to produce a filtered array:

```
var res = str
    .Split(new[] {',', ' '})
    .Where(s => s.Any(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)))
    .ToList();
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/eucNte).

Comment: Upvoted this one since this encourages the question asker to do his homework instead of chewing it out for him. -edit: and undone.

Comment: how?? can u please explain with example?

Comment: Yeah, the result sample is a string but something else is OK too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"105, c#, vb, 345, 53, sql51".Split(",")
       .Where(item => new Regex("[#A-Za-z0-9]").IsMatch(item))
           .Select(item=> item.Trim())
                 .ToList();
```

Note: Not sure why the OP wants the numbers filtered out-- Numbers are alphanumeric.

Comment: Please, consider strings with numbers only.

Comment: You forgot to support the `#` (and all the other non-numeric characters that might be present)

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks-- still a bit confused about what results OP expects to get. Assuming # is acceptable, aren't all the numbers in that list alphanumeric?

Comment: @ek_ny Yes, agreed - I think it's not well specified in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var str = "test,test,tes,123,5";
var result = string.Join(",", str.Split(',').Where(s => !s.All(t => Char.IsNumber(t))));
result.Dump();
```